# Does Scripture Mention Jacob eating meat?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

I remember that Jacob gives Esau some of his lentil stew, and that he makes a big deal telling Lavan that he never ate of Lavans flock. Is there a scripture that shows or talks about Jacob eating meat?

Comment: וַיִּזְבַּח יַעֲקֹב זֶבַח בָּהָר, וַיִּקְרָא לְאֶחָיו לֶאֱכָל-לָחֶם; וַיֹּאכְלוּ לֶחֶם, וַיָּלִינוּ בָּהָר is certainly suggestive of eating meat sandwiches. זבח is usually a shelamim-eating-type offering as opposed to olah

Comment: @DoubleAA What's the chapter and verse?

Comment: @DoubleAA Genesis 31:57

Comment: Why would you assume he did not eat meat?

Answer (score 1):

> So Jacob took an oath in the name of the Fear of his father Isaac.  He offered a sacrifice there in the hill country and invited his relatives to a meal.  After they had eaten, they spent the night there (Genesis 31, last few verses).

Bear in mind that this act establishes a covenant between Laban and Jacob.

Abraham was tested by G-d, being asked to sacrifice his beloved child of the promise, Isaac. G-d spared Isaac by providing a ram for sacrifice (Genesis chapter 22).  No wonder Jacob was sensitive to the covenant arrangement that required the sacrifice of an animal.

Up there, in the hill country, what sort of a sacrifice would Jacob offer?  Vegetables or grain?  What sort of sacrifice is pleasing to G-d?

Another covenant is described in Exodus chapter 24.  When Moses obeyed the command to build an altar at the foot of the mountain, he set up twelve stone pillars representing the twelve tribes of Israel.  Young bulls were sacrificed and half of the blood was sprinkled on the altar.  The other half was sprinkled on the people.

Just because Jacob did not eat the meat of the flocks owned by Laban does not mean to infer Jacob never ate meat.

Comment: Who said any of these people ate from the animal sacrifice? Maybe it was entirely burnt?

Comment: The issur of eating *gid hanoshe* implies that they ate other parts of the animals.

Comment: Certainly Isaac ate meat, that is what Genesis 27 is all about. But, maybe Jacob was different. Who knows.